# What is the file construction and organization in iOS development?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, code-organization

I am confused by file organization in iOS development. Must a view have a corresponding view controller? Should all the delegate methods be put in the delegate file? Do UI components have corresponding files?

Comment: You should just search the web for iOS Tutorials. This is a question and answer site for specific problems and issues. In addition, these questions have been asked hundreds of times. Please use the search function.

Comment: You can check the apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1 also Ray Wenderlich has GREAT stuff http://www.raywenderlich.com/

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use UIView without UIController
2.The UI components have theirs corresponding(mainly the UIViewController)